# Arredondamento de horas (de 30 em 30 minutos)

Tags: microsoft-excel, time

Alguém tem ideia de alguma lógica para arredondamento de hora, porém de 30 em 30 minutos?

Exemplo:

```
vem assim -> vira assim
15:34:32 -> 15:30 
15:47:21 -> 15:30 
16:00:40 -> 16:00
17:28:30 -> 17:00
```

Comment: Sempre vai arredondar para baixo?

Comment: sua solução é muito útil, mas como é para pausa de funcionário, passou da 16:00 é 16:00, passou das 16:30 é 16:30, passou das 17:00 é 17:00, entende?

Comment: Veja minha edição

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a função [`MARRED`](https://support.office.com/pt-br/article/MARRED-Fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-MARRED--c299c3b0-15a5-426d-aa4b-d2d5b3baf427?ui=pt-BR&rs=pt-BR&ad=BR) (ou `MROUND` se seu Office for em Inglês). Ela retorna um número arredondado ao múltiplo desejado.

Para usar com horários, faça assim:

```
=MARRED(A2;"0:30")
```

Para arrendondar sempre para baixo, faça assim:

```
=MARRED(A2-"0:15";"0:30")
```

Resultado:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: perfeitamente, muito obrigado.